# How can I replace all occurrences of a value in a text file just in one column using the Sed command in shell script (columns are seperated by ;)?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a file that has columns seperated by a semi column(;) and I want to change all occurrences of a word in a particular column only to another word. The column number differentiates based on the variable that holds the column number. The word I want to change is stored in a variable, and the word I want to change to is stored in a variable too.

I tried

```
sed -i "s/\<$word\>/$wordUpdate/g" $anyFile
```

I tried this but it changed all occurrences of word in the whole file! I only want in a particular column

the number of column is stored in a variable called numColumn
and the columns are seperated by a semi column ;

Comment: When dealing with "columns", you should use `awk` rather than `sed`.

Comment: If you follow [these guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are more likely to receive good answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is much simpler to use `awk` for column edits, e.g. if your input looks like this:

```
68;61;83;27;60;70;84;11;46;62;93;97;40;23;19
33;70;17;49;81;21;68;83;16;6;42;38;68;81;89
73;40;95;64;32;33;77;56;23;11;70;28;33;80;24
8;9;74;6;86;78;87;41;11;79;23;28;71;99;15
29;87;77;9;98;12;7;66;60;85;20;14;55;97;17
39;24;21;58;23;61;39;26;57;70;76;16;70;53;8
37;46;18;64;56;28;86;7;80;71;94;46;19;53;43
71;2;47;62;9;21;68;9;9;80;32;59;73;74;72
20;34;89;58;74;92;86;35;48;81;50;6;63;67;90
78;17;6;63;61;65;75;31;33;82;24;5;90;46;12
```

You can replace `60` in column `c` with `s` with something like this:

```
<infile awk '$c ~ m { $c = s } 1' FS=';' OFS=';' c=5 m=60 s=XX
```

Output:

```
68;61;83;27;XX;70;84;11;46;62;93;97;40;23;19
33;70;17;49;81;21;68;83;16;6;42;38;68;81;89
73;40;95;64;32;33;77;56;23;11;70;28;33;80;24
8;9;74;6;86;78;87;41;11;79;23;28;71;99;15
29;87;77;9;98;12;7;66;60;85;20;14;55;97;17
39;24;21;58;23;61;39;26;57;70;76;16;70;53;8
37;46;18;64;56;28;86;7;80;71;94;46;19;53;43
71;2;47;62;9;21;68;9;9;80;32;59;73;74;72
20;34;89;58;74;92;86;35;48;81;50;6;63;67;90
78;17;6;63;61;65;75;31;33;82;24;5;90;46;12
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
word=foo wordUpdate=bar numColumn=3
sed -i 'y/;/\n/
        s#.*#echo "&" | sed "'${numColumn}'s/\<'${word}'\>/'${wordUpdate}'/"#e
        y/\n/;/' file
```

Convert each line into a separate file where the columns are lines.

Substitute the matching line (column number) with the word for the updated word.

Reverse the conversion.

N.B. The solution relies on the GNU only `e` evaluation flag. Also the `word` and `updateWord` may need to be quoted.

Comment: Upvote for creativity, though it pains me to see that kind of sub-spawning.  Maybe a test to see if `$word` appears in that column first? Though that would require more code to construct the test before executing, which changes the paradigm a lot... Cool idea though.

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be done with a little creativity...
Note that I'm using double-quotes to embed the logic. This takes a little extra care  to double your `\`'s on backreferences.

```
$: word=baz; c=3; new=XX; lead="^([^;]*;){$((c-1))}"; sed -E "/$lead$word;/{s/($lead)$word/\\1$new/}" file
 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0;
 foo;bar;XX;qux;foo;bar;baz;qux;
 a;b;c;d;e;f;g;
```

Explained:
`lead="^([^;]*;){$((c-1))}"`

- `^` means *at the start of a record*
- `(...)` is grouping for the following `{...}` which specified repetition
- `[^;]*` mean *zero or more non-semicolons*
- `$((c-1))` does the math and returns one less than the desired column; if you want to look at column 3, it returns two.
- *SO*, `^([^;]*;){$((c-1))}` at the start of the record, *one-less-than-column* occurrences of non-semicolons followed by a semicolon

thus, `sed -E "/$lead$word;/{s/($lead)$word/\\1$new/}" file` mean read `file` and on records where `$word` occurs *in the requested column*, save everything before it, and put that stuff back, but replace `$word` with `$new`.

Even if you MUST use `sed`, I recommend a function.

```
fix(){ 
  local word="$1" col="$2" new="$3" file="$4"
  local lead="^([^;]*;){$((col-1))}"
  sed -E "/$lead$word;/{s/($lead)$word/\\1$new/}" "$file"
}
```

In use -

```
$: fix bar 2 HI file
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0;
foo;HI;baz;qux;foo;bar;baz;qux;
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;

$: fix 1 1 XX file
XX;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0;
foo;bar;baz;qux;foo;bar;baz;qux;
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;

$: fix bar 2 '(^_^)' file
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0;
foo;(^_^);baz;qux;foo;bar;baz;qux;
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;
```

No changes if no matches -

```
$: fix bar 5 HI file
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0;
foo;bar;baz;qux;foo;bar;baz;qux;
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;
```

## NOTE -

This logic requires trailing delimiters if you ever want to match the last field -

```
$: fix 0 10 HI file
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;HI;
foo;bar;baz;qux;foo;bar;baz;qux;
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;
```

delimiters removed:

```
$: fix 0 10 HI file
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0
foo;bar;baz;qux;foo;bar;baz;qux
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
```

Otherwise you have to complicate the logic a bit.

But honestly, for field parsing, you'd be so much better served to use `awk`, or even `perl` or `python`, or for that matter a `bash` loop, though that's going to be relatively slow.